# Conjugation and tenses

Tags: conjugación

I am just trying to write a little piece about myself but sometimes struggle with conjugation. 
Is the correct tense **present** when describing myself?

i.e:

> Creo que soy una persona muy independiente, pero un poco desordenada.

Comment: It sounds perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  `Ser` in the present indicative tense is the appropriate one.

Using any other tense would describe yourself in the past, or the future, or in a hypothetical situation (like in a fairy tale)

`Estoy muy hablador` would mean something like, `I'm talking a lot`... while

`Soy muy hablador` would mean, `I talk a lot` or more colloquially, `I'm a talker`

Comment: thank you, in addition if I was talking about my mother could I write "mi madre es muy hablador"?

Comment: Correct, unless you were talking about your mother being a talkative person at a particular moment and not all the time, then you might say that your mother `está muy hablador` bit.ly/1sgebhI

Comment: "madre" is femenine, so you must match the gender: Mi madre es muy habladorA

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you did it well.

If you need past you can use (yo era) or (yo he sido) and with future can be (yo seré)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are absolutely right. Spanish here has the same conventions as English.

When you are describing yourself in English, you use the present tense as well:

> "I **am** very hardworking", "I **am** somewhat shy"

In Spanish, you use the same present tense:

> "**Soy** muy trabajador", "**Soy** algo tímido"